# Specify app dependency in migration

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I'm trying to add initial data in Django 1.7 and I've read that it is recommended to use data migrations.

I've created my migration file correctly, called "0001_groups", in which I create few `contrib.auth`'s groups and permissions.

The problem is that it is run before the `auth` migrations are run.

I went to find out what't the name of the [last migration of the `auth` app](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/auth/migrations), and it's called `0005_alter_user_last_login_null.py`. So I tried with:

```
dependencies = [
    ('auth', '0005_alter_user_last_login_null'),
]
```

but I get:

> KeyError: u"Migration appname.0001_groups dependencies references
>   nonexistent parent node ('auth', '0005_alter_user_last_login_null')"

I've googled that error and it always links to 11 months old fixed bugs of Django.

How can I correctly specify the `auth` app dependency?

Comment: Have you tried `django.contrib.auth` instead of  `auth`  in specifying  dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `1.7` but looking at the `master` source tree. See [this](https://github.com/django/django/tree/1.7/django/contrib/auth/migrations) and try `0001_initial`.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed. I ended up using `__latest__`. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `__first__` if `0001_initial` is actually what you want.

Answer (score 21):

I've found out that you can reference the last migration with `__latest__`:

```
dependencies = [
    ('auth', '__latest__'),
]
```

Comment: In general, though, you don't *want* to reference the latest migration. What if you have a `ForeignKey` to a Model that is later deleted? Your migration will break. It's unlikely to matter with a stable package like `django.contrib.auth` but it's still bad practice and doesn't gain you anything.

Comment: Not at all, that's not how migrations work. Note that `makemigrations` produces dependencies on *specific* migrations, not `__latest__`, and that the Django source code itself references specific migrations in its dependencies (e.g. [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/flatpages/migrations/0001_initial.py)). For more on the problems with using `__latest__` see [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23071).

Comment: I suggest that you post a new question, along with your code, explaining the problem you're having. There's not enough to go on here. The point about custom `Managers` is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#historical-models). To make migrations work Django has to have a versioned, *textual* representation of your models, and because "it's impossible to serialize arbitrary Python code" that representation can't include custom methods or `Managers`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to depend on the very first migration of whatever the `django.conf.setting.AUTH_USER_MODEL` is set to, so that I don't have to hard-code the app name in my code.

The following will do just that:

```
dependencies = [migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)]
```

which is equivalent to:

```
dependencies = [(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.rsplit(".")[0], "__first__")]
```